# Comparing two datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a Datagridview (called DGW5 in the code below, which has always 8 rows) that I have to compare with another Datagridview (called DGW3 in the code below). The two datagridview have obviously the same number of columns (equal to 3). If the rows of the two Datagridview are equal one to each other, I have to add the index of the row (plus 1) of the DGW3 in a Listbox.

```
    For i = 0 To DataGridView3.Rows.Count - 2
        If DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value Then
            ListBox22.Items.Add(CInt(i + 1))
        End If
        If DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(1).Cells(0).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(1).Cells(2).Value Then
            ListBox22.Items.Add(CInt(i + 1))
        End If
        If DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(2).Cells(0).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(2).Cells(1).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(2).Cells(2).Value Then
            ListBox22.Items.Add(CInt(i + 1))
        End If
        If DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(3).Cells(0).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(3).Cells(1).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(3).Cells(2).Value Then
            ListBox22.Items.Add(CInt(i + 1))
        End If
        If DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(4).Cells(0).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(4).Cells(1).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(4).Cells(2).Value Then
            ListBox22.Items.Add(CInt(i + 1))
        End If
        If DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(5).Cells(0).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(5).Cells(1).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(5).Cells(2).Value Then
            ListBox22.Items.Add(CInt(i + 1))
        End If
        If DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(6).Cells(0).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(6).Cells(1).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(6).Cells(2).Value Then
            ListBox22.Items.Add(CInt(i + 1))
        End If
        If DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(7).Cells(0).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(7).Cells(1).Value And DataGridView3.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView5.Rows(7).Cells(2).Value Then
            ListBox22.Items.Add(CInt(i + 1))
        End If
    Next
```

As output, I'm just having back the numbers from 1 to 8 but that's not the exact output data. Does anyone know how this issue could be solved? Thanks in advance all are gonna answer me. Best regards

Comment: Not clear what you are doing here, or what the question is.

Comment: I have to compare each row of the DGW5 to the rows of the DGW3. When if finds that the row in DGW5 is equal to a row in DGW3, I need the index of the abovementioned row in the DGW3. Hope it's clearer now

Comment: What value(s) are you getting in the ListBox22?  What are in the cells?  Numbers?  Strings?  Why are you checking every row if you are looping?  You only need one If-Block, just change the `Rows(0..7)` to `Rows(i)`.

Comment: In the listbox22 I have to add the index of the row. Both in the DGW3 and in the DGW5 there are numbers. I'm checking every row as this because the number of the rows of DGW3 and DGW5 in not the same.

Comment: Right.  Like I said, get rid of those 7 extra If-Then blocks.

Comment: Perfect, now it's working. Thanks a lot